# Green's Theorem - Applying a translation to the vector field to make the integral easier to evaluate

Tags: coordinate-systems, line-integrals, greens-theorem

I have to evaluate a line integral using Green's theorem:

$$\overrightarrow{F}(x,y)=\langle y-\cos{y}, x\sin{y} \rangle$$

The curve $C$ is the circle $(x-3)^2+(y+4)^2=4$, oriented clockwise.

It would be much easier to solve the double integral using polar coordinates, except the circle has been translated and writing the translation in polar coordinates makes the function "ugly". At which point you may as well just evaluate it using Cartesian coordinates.

My idea was to move the circle and the vector field together such that the circle will be centered at the origin and the vector field follows. What I get is:

$$\overrightarrow{F}(x,y)=\langle (y-4)-\cos{(y-4)}, (x+3)\sin(y-4) \rangle$$

and $C$ becomes $x^2+y^2=4$. Now you can convert to polar coordinates, with $0 \leq r \leq 2$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

Is this valid? Or is there some way to simplify the coordinates that I am missing?

Comment: well, in general, there is a trade-off between what becomes simpler. Often, you can make the domain simpler, or alternatively, the function/vector field simpler. If you’re lucky, both are possible, and if you’re unlucky, neither is possible. Deciding which is “better” for a problem is only answerable on a case-by-case basis, and the “correct” choice comes, as expected, with practice. But, first, what does Green’s theorem say?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, but here we don't really need it.

Indeed, by Green's theorem, the line integral is equal to
$$\begin{align}-\iint_{D}({F_2}_x-{F_1}_y)\,dx dy&=-\iint_{D}(\sin(y)-(1+\sin(y))\,dx dy\\
&=\iint_{D}1\,dx dy=|D|=4\pi
\end{align}$$
where $D$ is the disc $\{(x,y):(x-3)^2+(y+4)^2\leq 4\}$ and $|D|=\pi \cdot 2^2=4\pi$ is its area (which is invariant under translations and rotations).

Comment: Thank you @Robert, that clears it up! What I understand from your answer which I didn't realise is that, in the special case where the integrand is 1, the value of the integral is independent of position.

Comment: @LeonardoCucinotta Yes, $\iint_{D}1\,dx dy$ is the area of $D$ which invariant under translations (and rotations)